# Distribution of min(X+Y,Y+Z,X+Z,Z+V,X+V,Y+V)?

Tags: self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics

Let $X,Y,Z,V$ be i.i.d continuous random variables in an interval $[a,b]$. What will be the distribution of $\min(X+Y,Y+Z,X+Z,Z+V,X+V,Y+V)$? Assume the distribution of the random variables to be $F(.)$, with $F(a)=0$ and $F(b)=1$.

My attempt:-

Let $W=\min(X+Y,Y+Z,X+Z, Z+V,X+V,Y+V)$. We need to find $P(W\leq w)$. This means $P(X+Y \leq w \wedge Y+Z\leq w\wedge X+Z\leq w \wedge Z+V\leq w\wedge X+V\leq w\wedge Y+V\leq w)$. But these sums are not independent, so I wasn't able to proceed further.

What should be the general approach for such problems?

Comment: Please erase the last probability expression which is not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your notations do not help. Rephrase the problem as
$$X_1,\ldots,X_4\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} f(x)$$
and
$$Y=\min\{X_1+X_2,X_1+X_3,X_1+X_4,X_2+X_3,X_2+X_4,X_3+X_4\}$$
You can then express $Y$ in terms of the order statistics
$$X_{(1)}\le X_{(2)}\le X_{(3)}\le X_{(4)}$$
and deduce that $Y$ is a specific sum of two of these order statistics, which leads to the conclusion. Indeed, 
$$Y=X_{(1)}+X_{(2)}$$
and, since
$$(X_{(1)},X_{(2)})\sim \frac{4!}{2!}f(x_{(1)})f(x_{(1)})[1-F(x_{(2)})]^2$$
one can derive the distribution of $Y$ from a convolution step:
$$Y\sim\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{4!}{2!}f(x_{(1)})f(y-x_{(1)})[1-F(y-x_{(1)})]^2\,\text{d}x_{(1)}$$

Comment: I get your point. I'm supposed to find out the distribution of $X_{(1)} + X_{(2)}$ now. But order statistics are not independent, so do you have any idea what should I do next?